# (Graph) - How to find number of vertices given number of edges and some information on the degrees of vertices?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Graph G has 21 edges, 3 vertices which have a degree of 4, other vertices have a degree of 3. How many vertices are there in total?

Comment: Do you know about the handshaking lemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the sum of degree across all nodes is equal to twice the number of edges [(Handshaking Lemma)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma). Let there be $N$ vertices in this graph.

We have 
$$
\begin{align}
3 \cdot 4 + 3 \cdot (N-3) &= 2 \cdot 21 \\
12 + 3 \cdot (N-3)&= 42\\
3 \cdot (N-3)&= 30 \\
(N-3) &= 10\\
N &= 13\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure if I could do that so I feel stupid for asking this question. Cheers